# Condition that CR equation implies holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

There are many version of criterion for a function to be holomoprhic when CR equation holds ,for example in Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis book has a version that :

> **Theorem $2.4$** Suppose $f=u+i v$ is a complex-valued function defined on an open set $\Omega .$ If $u$ and $v$ are continuously differentiable and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations on $\Omega$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $f^{\prime}(z)=\partial f / \partial z$

I paste the proof below:

Proof. Write
$$
u\left(x+h_{1}, y+h_{2}\right)-u(x, y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} h_{1}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} h_{2}+|h| \psi_{1}(h)
$$
and
$$
v\left(x+h_{1}, y+h_{2}\right)-v(x, y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} h_{1}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} h_{2}+|h| \psi_{2}(h)
$$
where $\psi_{j}(h) \rightarrow 0$ (for $j=1,2$ ) as $|h|$ tends to 0 (**in this step we use differentiable of $u,v$**), and $h=h_{1}+i h_{2}$. Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations we find that
$$
f(z+h)-f(z)=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\left(h_{1}+i h_{2}\right)+|h| \psi(h)
$$
where $\psi(h)=\psi_{1}(h)+\psi_{2}(h) \rightarrow 0$, as $|h| \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $f$ is holomorphic and
$$
f^{\prime}(z)=2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
$$

There are some observation here,First we can find that to check $f$ holomorphic at some point,we only need to check that:

(1)$f$ has $u,v $ is $C^1$ at that point

(2) CR equation holds at that point.

I found in the proof,we only use the fact that $u,v$ is differentiable ,do not need $u,v$ be continuous differentialbe at that point correct?

See relavent question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3639947/360262) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696394/360262)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get this answered: yes, you're right. We only need $u,v$ to be (Frechet) differentiable (as maps between open sets of $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$) at the point in question, and for CR equations to hold at that point in order for $f$ to be complex-differentiable at the point (this is actually an equivalance). Stein and Shakarchi make the assumption that $u,v$ are $C^1$. This is a slightly stronger assumption, which is not needed.

Note also that this does not contradict anything mentioned in David C. Ullrich's answer.